# i want to view something in the internet, how can i do it? 

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode3.2

i want to view something in the internet, how can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't delete the question after it was answered. Instead upvote helpful answers (clicking on the up arrow left of the answer) and accept the best one (clicking on the checkmark). You can also leave comments to the answers if you want to add something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fails, route your WLAN over a box on which you install a network sniffer. Dump the HTTP traffic. That's the last resort solution, but for sure works.

Answer (score 0):

Generally user agent sniffing is the only method used to detect iPhones. You can use the develop menu in Safari to change your user agent string. An example iPhone user agent string is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5
```

Alternatively, you can add a [bookmarklet by Shaun Inman](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/11/16/mobilesafari_view_source) to Mobile Safari that allows you to view source code on your device (or just visit [the page](http://shauninman.com/vs/?url=) directly).

Comment: Could you share the link you're trying to get the source code for?

Comment: The problem is that the site uses a piece of javascript to redirect you if it detects your screen width is greater than 1024px. Disable javascript in your browser and visit `http://iphonetv.es/index.php` (and also set your user agent string to an iPhone-like agent).

Comment: I'm not following. Have you got the source code you were after? I works perfectly for me in Safari following these steps: Set user agent to iPhone, disable javascript, visit `http://iphonetv.es/index.php`, view source.

Comment: Sure can, just choose my answer as the best!